# Send byte array through MQTT - JavaScript Paho Eclipse

Tags: javascript, arrays, mqtt, paho

I have connected MQTT broker via Eclipse Paho JavaScript Client and from an arduino I'm getting messages something like this: 3 1 0 255, where every byte is something (temperature, pressure and etc...) and thats fine, but now I want to send message like **32 0 1 2 3 4 10 1 20** where every byte is also something, but when I'm trying to send this message  - I'm getting it in ASCII instead of decimals. I mean, I get an hex for 3, another one for 2, another one for space and so on.

```
$('#clicktest').click(function() {
var ms = "32,0,1,2,3,4,10,1,20";
sendMes(ms);
});

function sendMes(mes) {
message = new Paho.MQTT.Message(mes);
message.destinationName = "test/g";
client.send(message);
}
```

I googled first and as I understand I should send the integers as byte array, but I didn't quit understand how can I wrap this numbers as byte array and send them to broker so it was not converted to ASCII.

I'm new in this mqtt stuff, so please could you please give me a direction?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really MQTT specific, but you need to use something like a [uint8array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) to hold the data.

e.g.

```
$('#clicktest').click(function() {
  var ms = new Uint8Array([32,0,1,2,3,4,10,1,20]);
  sendMes(ms);
});

function sendMes(mes) {
  message = new Paho.MQTT.Message(mes);
  message.destinationName = "test/g";
  client.send(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your sender is on Arduino why don't you show the actual sending code or how the data actually looks like when received on the js side? The js code that you shared may or may not behave the same as your Arduino code.

Ignoring that for now: you can send the data as JSON

```
$('#clicktest').click(function() {
var ms = [32,0,1,2,3,4,10,1,20];
sendMes(JSON.stringify(ms));
});
```

and parse the JSON at the receiving end trivially.

JSON encoding will cause a little bit of overhead, but makes the payload human readable and is robust: for example if you need to start sending floats JSON will handle it nicely.